# UIScrollView doesn't work properly (it backs to top and not shows any scrollers

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, interface-builder

I'm doing an iphone app where I've severals UILabels, UITextfields and UIButtons. I need show them in a screen with more 480px of height, so I've introducing them into an UIView. Later, I've created an UIScroller for show them.

Its struct in interface builder is:

- View controller

  - ---> View (it isn't resizable and may be obligatory)

    - ---> Scrollview

      - ---> View

        - ---> Labels
        - ---> TextFields

I've set UIScrollView contentsize's and UIView frame below "User Defined Runtine Attributes" in "Identity Inspector" (on Interface Builder) and show them in Console Log when app runs. Seems be ok, but UIScrollView always back to top when I scroll it down and its scrolls weren't shown.

I've search a lot in this forum I haven't found any solution.

Can anybody help me? Thanks!

Edit: I added on my code this to show their defined values (uploadView is the view in scrollView)

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
//....  
[super viewDidLoad];
    CGSize size = scrollView.contentSize;
CGRect viewrect = uploadView.frame;
CGSize viewsize = viewrect.size;
NSLog (@"size of scrollView: height= %f and width= %f", size.height, size.width);
NSLog (@"size of uploadView: height= %f and width= %f", viewsize.height, viewsize.width);
```

}

The outputs are:

```
size of scrollview: height= 600.000000 and width= 320.0000000
size of uploadview: height= 600.000000 and width= 320.0000000
```

Comment: post some code. There seems no issue from question.

Comment: fibnochi is right, some code would help. But it sounds like you are not set the content size of UIScrollView. Something like scrollview.contentSize = CGSize(width,height) (i wrote this from memory, probably has sintax issues. Try it in the old way, put a big number on height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've continued searching for any answer and I've found the solution.

[I can't get my scrollview to scroll correctly with objects such as 'round rect buttons' or labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14417858/i-cant-get-my-scrollview-to-scroll-correctly-with-objects-such-as-round-rect-b)

Sum up, using viewDidAppear method

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];

  [scrollview setScrollEnabled:YES];
  [scrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 600)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell exactly what your problem is without any code, but you could maybe try setting the content size in code:

> scrollView.contentSize = view.size

Where view is the UIView in your scrollview

```
•---> Scrollview 
    •---> View
```